# Weird stack trace growth with async/await and TaskCompletionSource

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

The following C# code:

```
class Program
{
    static readonly List<TaskCompletionSource<bool>> buffer = 
                new List<TaskCompletionSource<bool>>();
    static Timer timer;

    public static void Main()
    {
        var outstanding = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
            .Select(Enqueue)
            .ToArray();

        timer = new Timer(x => Flush(), null, 
                         TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                         TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));
        try
        {
            Task.WaitAll(outstanding);
        }
        catch {}

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static Task Enqueue(int i)
    {
        var task = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        buffer.Add(task);
        return task.Task;
    }

    static void Flush()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("test");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            foreach (var each in buffer)
            {
                var lenBefore = e.StackTrace.Length;
                each.TrySetException(e);
                var lenAfter = e.StackTrace.Length;
                Console.WriteLine($"Before - After: {lenBefore} - {lenAfter}");
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Produces:

```
Before - After: 149 - 149
Before - After: 149 - 149
Before - After: 149 - 149
Before - After: 149 - 149
Before - After: 149 - 149
Before - After: 149 - 149
Before - After: 149 - 149
Before - After: 149 - 149
Before - After: 149 - 149
Before - After: 149 - 149
```

But when I change `Enqueue` method to async:

```
static async Task Enqueue(int i)
{
    var task = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    buffer.Add(task);
    return await task.Task;
}
```

The result is:

```
Before - After: 149 - 643
Before - After: 643 - 1137
Before - After: 1137 - 1631
Before - After: 1631 - 2125
Before - After: 2125 - 2619
Before - After: 2619 - 3113
Before - After: 3113 - 3607
Before - After: 3607 - 4101
Before - After: 4101 - 4595
Before - After: 4595 - 5089
```

It looks like stack trace growth recursively for each buffered item. For the first item exception stack trace will be:

```
   at Program.Flush() in C:\src\Program.cs:line 41
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotificati...
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Program.<Enqueue>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\src\Program.cs:line 34
```

While second will look like below and so on:

```
   at Program.Flush() in C:\src\Program.cs:line 41
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotificati...
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Program.<Enqueue>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\src\Program.cs:line 34
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotificati...
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Program.<Enqueue>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\src\Program.cs:line 34
```

What is going on here and how to fix it?

Comment: UPDATE: I end up creating special exception like BatchException and passing original exception as inner exception as was suggested by @Dmitry. In my opinion it is the most succinct and right way to fix this problem. Until better times ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: `await` tries to unwrap result, while method withod `await` does not try to access task result.

Longer answer:

1. The recurring part of call stack have the following look:

[image: RecurrringCallStack]

2. The [ValidateEnd](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/ef08c8221aa4d33f6ad1399d13bdaab9b10b84a0/src/mscorlib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs#L116) method of `TaskAwaiter` is being inlined, and the [HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/ef08c8221aa4d33f6ad1399d13bdaab9b10b84a0/src/mscorlib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs#L132) causes a call to [ThrowForNonSuccess](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/ef08c8221aa4d33f6ad1399d13bdaab9b10b84a0/src/mscorlib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs#L155) which seems to be inlined too and, as single exception is used to set result for 10 `TaskCompletionSource`s,  [the reason of growing stack of that exception can be seen here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/ef08c8221aa4d33f6ad1399d13bdaab9b10b84a0/src/mscorlib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs#L182).

Simple solution is to use `new Exception("Some descriptive message", originalException)`  on each `TrySetException` call.

Comment: Great explanation! But I need to retain original exception as this is the part of generic solution and consumer may want to catch an original exception, i.e. it could be ConcurrencyConflictException thrown by AzureSDK. Is there more sane way how to fix it?

Comment: Wrapping original exception in new one requires all consumers to unwrap and do additional check  ((

Comment: On full .Net framework there's a way - one can make deep copy of exception with `BinaryFormatter`, but such solution won't work on .Net Core

Comment: In case of dire need in .Net core - https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/blob/master/src/Orleans/Serialization/ILBasedExceptionSerializer.cs could be extracted.

Comment: Nope, that won't work. Cloning leads to stack trace loss

Comment: Just checked cloning with 'BinaryFormatter' - stack trace was preserved.

Comment: Can you show me the code, since in my tests it lost

Comment: Here's the code https://gist.github.com/dVakulen/d15db18e889f2dee5cf1cc77ebf08828

Comment: try running this code )) https://gist.github.com/yevhen/2f53f923d30b2d5e1ed0acb13034475c

Comment: @YevhenBobrov Yep, should've known that.. Anyway - here's working solution https://gist.github.com/dVakulen/a8d0acaf1e7ba1835c27792230ddc3e5 . Had to use a bit of magic, but should be ok for this case.

Comment: Cool. But this won't work with exceptions which not marked as Serializable. I gave up and chosen you original answer (wrapping exception). See this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467275/weird-stack-trace-growth-with-async-await-and-taskcompletionsource#comment80134759_46467275)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are reusing the same exception for each task, so it appends all the stacks together assuming that is the sequence they progressed in.

If you instead create a new exception for each

```
var ex = new Exception(e.Message, e);
each.TrySetException(ex);
```

Then you'll get

```
Before - After: 87 - 341
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Program.<Enqueue>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\src\Program.cs:line 34
Before - After: 87 - 341
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Program.<Enqueue>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\src\Program.cs:line 34
Before - After: 87 - 341
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Program.<Enqueue>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\src\Program.cs:line 34
Before - After: 87 - 341
```

If you also use the [Ben.Demystifier](https://github.com/benaadams/Ben.Demystifier) library

```
var ex = new Exception(e.Message, e);
each.TrySetException(ex);
var lenAfter = ex.Demystify().StackTrace.Length;
```

Then that will come down even further:

```
Before - After: 87 - 105
   at async Task Program.Enqueue(int i) in C:\src\Program.cs:line 34
Before - After: 92 - 105
   at async Task Program.Enqueue(int i) in C:\src\Program.cs:line 34
Before - After: 92 - 105
   at async Task Program.Enqueue(int i) in C:\src\Program.cs:line 34
Before - After: 92 - 105
```

Comment: Thanks, Ben! Demystifier is awesome! ))

Comment: I understand the solution but it doesn't completely solve the problem. Imagine if that exception is coming from 3rd party code (like Azure SDK). I can't (re)create new instances of those for each task.

I end up creating special BatchItemException but it's still a lossy solution